# matplotlib polar plot axis label position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been playing with polar plots for some time now, but can't figure out how I get my axis labels automatically placed in the correct spot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], projection="polar")

r = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=5, size=50)
theta = np.deg2rad(np.random.normal(loc=190, scale=2, size=50))

# Plot
ax.scatter(theta, r)

# Adjust limits
ax.set_rorigin(0)
ax.set_thetamin(180)
ax.set_thetamax(200)
ax.set_rmin(40)
ax.set_rmax(60)

# Labels
ax.set_xlabel("r")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$\theta$")

plt.show()
```

This produces such a plot:
https://ibb.co/geo4WK

[image]

As you can see, the "r" label does not appear on the top axis where the tick labels are and I have similar problem for other ranges of theta. Is there a way to always have the axis label appear with the axis that has tick labels? Or can I have the tick labels for the radii always at the bottom axis?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.xaxis.set_label_coords()` to move "r" to the top center location. As the figure is set to be `(5,5)` and you have r limits adjusted, the "r" label should stay the same as you change `theta`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], projection="polar")

r = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=5, size=50)
theta = np.deg2rad(np.random.normal(loc=190, scale=2, size=50))

# Plot
ax.scatter(theta, r)

# Adjust limits
ax.set_rorigin(0)
ax.set_thetamin(180)
ax.set_thetamax(200)
ax.set_rmin(40)
ax.set_rmax(60)

# Labels
ax.set_xlabel("r")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$\theta$")
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, 1.05)

plt.show()
```

[image]